# PHP - Purpose of Constants?

Tags: php, oop, constants, global

What, exactly, is the purpose of using constants (in PHP)? I understand how they work, but in which circumstances are they preferable over, say, a global variable? If anything, wouldn't variables be more flexible because they can be placed inside strings?

I've searched the web, but all I've found is definitions--not actual reason for using one or the other. Can anyone help me to understand the benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: Use a constant when you don't want the value to change under any circumstance.

Comment: I'm voting to push this to Programmers.SE, where you're likely to get more detailed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant is dependable. It will not change.
Say for example You are writing a class library that others can use.
Say you want to use Pi to 5 decimal places, and forwhatever reason you don't want to make it a private variable with a getter.

So you do

```
   Class Foo {

       public $pi = 3.14159;
   }
```

Now some guy who is using your class accidently does

```
$foo->pi = 4;
```

Well that will screw everything up.
So instead, you do

```
const $pi = 3.14159;
```

Now you know it won't change and won't screw stuff up. Plus developers will know that you have defined it that specific value for a reason.

Comment: So it's just a way to keep developers from breaking their own code? Makes sense. :) Thanks!

Comment: Well yes and no...  Another type of constant is defines. These are good for application level settings. One might use it for a directory. define('DIR_CLASSES', '/classes'); This way someone can't change it at runtime as it wouldn't even make sense to be able to change it at runtime, but say in the future you move your classes directory to /subdir/classes you only need to change one line of code instead of updating many.

Comment: I might add this from the php manual: "Constants differ from normal variables in that you don't use the $ symbol to declare or use them." so it should be const pi = 3.14159 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

> in which circumstances are they preferable over, say, a global variable?

Constants don't change. Immutable global state would be preferred over its mutable counterpart; in that way, your state is defined in one location and never changes over the course of your script. Barring the use of `runkit` your code will not be able to change the state in some ways that you didn't expect.

Also, global variables must be declared inside functions by using the `global` keyword, though technically that declaration, albeit more type-work is better than assumed global I suppose :)

Comment: Redefine a constant. Hmm. I don't believe I've ever encountered anything less useful.

Comment: @Herbert I guess runkit has its usefulness, perhaps in running test cases without spawning multiple PHP processes? Not sure ...